# How can I scan strings with spaces in them using scanf()?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to write a sub-program in which a user can input their comment.
I use `scanf("%s", X)` and let them input a comment, but it can only store the word before a space bar in the string.

How can I solve this problem in order to store a whole sentence into a string or a file?

My code is presented below:

```
FILE *fp;
char comment[100];
fp=fopen("comment.txt","a");
printf("You can input your comment to our system or give opinion to the musics :\n");
scanf("%s",comment);
fputs(comment,fp);
```

Comment: `%s` isn't what you want if you want to add spaces, you want to use the negated scanset

Comment: Note: `scanf("%[^\n]", comment` will not scan anything into `comment` if the first `char` is `'\n'`, leaving `comment` uninitialized.

Answer (score 22):

Rather than the answers that tell you *not* to use `scanf()`, you can just the the [Negated scanset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) option of `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",comment); // This will read into the string: comment 
                           // everything from the next 99 characters up until 
                           // it gets a newline
```

Comment: Maybe `"%99[^\n]"` in this case?  BTW: This does have the side effect that the `\n` is not consumed and still in the input buffer.  Maybe use `" %99[^\n]"` (leading space) if this was in a loop?

Answer (score 13):

[**scanf()**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) with `%s` as format specifier reads a sequence of characters starting from the first non-whitespace character until (1) another whitespace character or (2) upto the field width if specified (e.g. `scanf("%127s",str);` -- read 127 characters and appends null byte as 128th), whichever comes first. And then automatically append null byte at the end. The pointer passed my be large enough to hold the input sequence of characters.

You can use **[fgets](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/gets.3.html)** to read the whole line:

```
fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
```

Note that fgets reads the newline character as well. You may want to get rid of the newline character from the `comment`.

Answer (score 3):

instead of scanf use `fgets` on stdin in order to read the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `gets()`, `getline()` functions to read string from `stdin`.

Comment: [`gets()` has been deprecated since C99](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890696/995714) and removed since C11. [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). And `getline()` is a POSIX function. It doesn't exist in C