# Entering a name or address with space into array

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)
>   [How can I scan strings with spaces in them using scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726499/how-can-i-scan-strings-with-spaces-in-them-using-scanf)

New to C and I feel this should be very simple but for some reason I'm not seeing the clear answer.

Trying to write a name and address to a file but if I put 'FirstName LastName' only FirstName gets entered into the file. Same with address. Is there a way to accept the whole name with the space into the file?

```
struct person{
     char name[20];
     char address[50];
     char telno[20];
} info;

fp=fopen("contacts","a")

printf("Enter Name : ");
scanf("%s",info.name);

printf("Enter Address : ");
scanf("%s",info.address);

fprintf(fp,"%20s %20s %20s",info.name,info.address,info.telno);
fclose(fp);
```

New to C so please excuse my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: Topic about using space with scanf -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: Don't use plain `scanf("%s", ...)`. Use `scanf("%19s", ...)` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to read "white space" in to a string with `scanf()` is with the negated scanset:

```
// This will read into comment everything up until the newline
scanf(" %[^\n]",info.name);
```

In general the answer you're going to get however is to "not use scanf" and use `fgets()` instead:

```
fgets(info.name, sizeof info.name, stdin);
```

Don't forget a lot of this info for [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) and others is easy to get with a quick search.

---

**Edit:** `I tried replacing scanf with fgets but when I run the program it skips past the "Enter Name:"`

If it's "skiping" by your `fgets()` that means that your `fgets()` just read a left over character that was sitting on the `stdin` buffer. I'd wager a guess it was a newline character.

When you enter a string:

```
john smith
```

You're getting a newline `'\n'` appended to the end after the `'h'`. That means `scanf()` is going to read the letters and leave the newline, `fgets()` on the other hand will read everything up to/including the newline. So if you were to do this:

```
scanf("%s",info.name);

fgets(info.address, sizeof info.address, stdin);
```

The `fgets()` would appear to be "skipped". If you're saying replacing both with `fgets()` is skipping the first one, then your `stdin` buffer isn't clean and you must have something before hand leaving a newline character on it.

Comment: I tried replacing scanf with `fgets(info.name, sizeof info.name, stdin);` but when I run the program it skips past the "Enter Name:" part and goes straight to "Enter Address:" (_Enter Name : Enter Address :_)

Comment: @fixafone123 - then you're not showing the whole code. Note: if you do this in a loop or a `scanf` or `getchar` prior to the `fgets` then you're going to just read a newline character (it will seem like it's skiping the "enter")

Comment: You can try and use fflush(stdin) to flush the buffer after you use scanf if you want to continue using scanf.

Comment: @AdmiralJonB - No. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. It should not be done and should not be recommended to be done.

Comment: @Mike, that was it. I have a selection menu that was getting input via scanf so my fgets was reading the newline character from that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike I had no idea it was undefined behaviour. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AdmiralJonB - NP. It's suggested all the time and is a bit of a pet peeve of mine. The man pages for `fflush()` says it works to clean the input buffer, but then they also say: `The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams`. So it typically works, but because it's not specified, it's technically UB.

Answer (score 3):

[`scanf(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html) stops converting arguments when it finds whitespace.  Try [`fgets(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fgets.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to accept the whole name with the space

Yes, use `fgets()` (it's generally advisable to use this function instead of `scanf()`, because `scanf()` doesn't always do what you think it does anyway):

```
fgets(info.name, sizeof(info.name), stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%[^\r\n]",info.name);

This means accept everything except CR and LF.