# Weird character appears when Inversing string in C

Tags: c, string, character

I want to inverse a string, so I wrote the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *inverseString(char *s);

char *inverseString(char *s)
{
    char *s1;
    int i = 0;
    s1 = (char*)malloc (strlen(s)+1);
    int j= strlen(s)-1;
    for (; j>=0; j--)  // dont know why for(; j> 0; j--) not work
    {

    s1[j] = s[i];
    i++;

    }
    return s1;

}
void main(void)
{
    char string[30];
    printf("string: ");
    gets(string);
    printf("inverse string is : %s",inverseString(string)); 
    getch();
}
```

But the result has a weird character at the end.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `gets()` ever, not even in toy programs.  It is no longer in standard C because it cannot be used safely — that is, the program cannot defend itself against malicious attack if it uses `gets()`.  Use `fgets()` and remember to remove the newline.

Answer (score 1):

The string must be terminated by **'\0'**. This is what marks the end of string.
The null character is often represented as the escape sequence \0 in source code string literals or character constants.

Here's more elegant inplace reversal:

```
void strrev(char *p)
{
  char *q = p;
  while(q && *q) ++q;
  for(--q; p < q; ++p, --q)
    *p = *p ^ *q,
    *q = *p ^ *q,
    *p = *p ^ *q;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  do {
    printf("%s ",  argv[argc-1]); strrev(argv[argc-1]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[argc-1]);
  } while(--argc);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should terminate your string with `NUL` character `\0`.

```
char *inverseString(char *s)
{   
    ...
    ...

    s1[++i] = '\0';  
    return s1;

}
```

**NOTE:** Do not use `gets` to read strings (it is removed from the standard now) rather you can use `fgets`.

```
fgets(string, 30, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is a string-reversing topic, where a pretty cool method is described: [Reversing a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c).

Then, I would advice not to use `gets()` as it [might be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) (`gets()` is actually the reason for your error to occur!).

Finally, here is the code, which might work well for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* No prototype for inverseString is required here, since the routine call occurs 
   after its implementation */

char *inverseString(char *s)
{
    char * s1;
    int i, j;

    s1 = (char *)malloc(strlen(s)+1);

    i = 0;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; j>=0; i++, j--) 
    {
        s1[i] = s[j];
    }

    return s1;

}

void main(void)
{
    char string[30];
    printf("string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &string);
    printf("inverse string is : %s", inverseString(string)); 
    getch();
}
```

Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728449/1714730) where I took `scanf("%[^\n]", &string)` construction from.