# Fgets skipping input and printing next line?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to read a string including spaces so scanf wouldn't work so I'm trying to use fgets. When I run it and it hits the if statement what prints on screen is:

```
Please enter the course name.
You entered the course: 


Please enter the course ID.
```

=======================

```
if(coursetotal==0)/*start of 1 course*/
    {

        printf("Please enter the course name.\n");
        fgets(course[0].name,sizeof(course[0].name),stdin);
        printf("You entered the course name: %s\n",course[0].name);


        printf("\nPlease enter the four digit course ID.\n");
        int temp=0,temp1=0,count=0; /*Variables used to check if 4 digits*/
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        temp1=temp;
        while(temp1!=0)
        {
            temp1/=10;
            count++;
        }
        if(count==4)/*start of is 4 digits*/
        {
            course[0].id=temp;
            coursetotal+=1;
            printf("You entered the course ID: %d\n",course[0].id);
        }/*end of is 4 digits*/
        else
        {
            printf("The course ID you input was not 4 digits.\n");
            return;
        }

        printf("You have successfully added the course: %s. The ID is : %d, and you now have a total of %d course.\n",course[0].name,course[0].id,coursetotal);

    } /*end 1 course*/
```

Comment: because in starting sizeof(course[0].name) is 0 so it's not taking any character......... read the fgets() function from the following location http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

Comment: You may have left a newline character in the input queue from some previous user interaction.  Try calling `getchar` ahead of `fgets` as a test.  The real solution depends on how you process that previous transaction.

Comment: @JatinKhurana How could `sizeof()` return a zero?

Comment: how about you start with checking your api function results. [The Sixth Commandment](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html) of C programming should be taken seriously from a young age, and the most common errors in beginner-code are all-too-often attributed to the naive assumption that if something usually works, it always will.

Comment: Avoid mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  As @user3386109, says, you have a left-over `\n` from a `scanf()` or such.  Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or `strtol()` to read the integer.

Comment: Really? `scanf` won't read spaces? [Sorry, but it does read past spaces, you just need the right options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13728449/1348709)

Answer (score 1):

First I have to address the pet peeve I see here:

> I'm trying to read a string including spaces so scanf wouldn't work

[That's not true at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728449/1348709) There's something called a [negated scanset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) you can use it to read past the white space characters (such as space) that normally terminate `scanf()`s input for a string.

That said. You should really pick just one input mechanism `scanf()` or `fgets()` and use that exclusively. When you intermix, things get weird and missed. The fact that you've done it here tells me you've done it other places and you probably used `scanf()` prior to this leaving yourself an "unclean" `stdin` buffer. This will fix your issue.

---

Now just a quick example for you, given a int (`num`) and a char * (`string):

```
scanf("%d", &num);
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
printf("%d\n%s\n", num, string);
```

You'll seemingly skip the ability to enter anything for the `fgets` as it really just took int the newline character leftover from the `scanf()`'s number entry. You'll see on the output something like:

```
5
5
               // <-- and a couple
              //  <-- of blank lines
```

Indicating that you picked up a newline character. Even more obvious if you were to look at the ASCII value of the string's first (and only) character:

```
printf("%d\n", string[0]);   // this would yield 10 the ASCII value of \n
```