# Why gets() is deprecated?

Tags: c, include, c-strings

While using `gets()` in my code, the compiler shouts

```
warning: the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`
```

and

```
warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638)
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Any specific reasons?

Comment: Use `fgets` with `stdin` instead. As the message says, `gets` is dangerous, since it provides no protection against buffer overflow..

Comment: The literal answer to "Why does the compiler emit a warning here?" is "Because the compiler's programmers made it do that."

Answer (score 6):

> *Can someone explains why the compiler shows like that…?*

Yes, because, the `gets()` function is dangerous, as it suffers from buffer overflow issue. Anyone should refrain from using that.

Also, regarding the warning with `-Wdeprecated-declarations`, `gets()` is no longer a part of `C` standard [`C11` onwards]. So, C libraries <del>compilers</del> are not *bound* to support that any more. It can be removed in future. To warn the developer about the potential pitfall and to discourage the further usage of `gets()`, the compiler<sup>##</sup> emits the warning message.

---

<sup>(##) To be pedantic, the warning is not generated by the compiler (`gcc`) all by itself, rather caused by a `pragma` or attribute on the implementation of `gets()` in the `glibc` that causes the compiler to emit the warning. [Courtesy, FUZxxl, from the dupe answer.]</sup>

Answer (score 2):

1. `gets` may cause buffer overflow, since it don't consider length of the data. More details are here : [gets() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346598/gets-function-in-c)
2. deprecated message means, this function is marked as deprecated and may remove from standard in later time. So  discouraging user to use it.