# Changing gets() to txt file input

Tags: c

I need to covert this code from a user input using gets() to scanning in an input txt file.
It would also be helpful to find a way to count the number of letters in every word. Starting with 1 letter words and on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void) {

    int acount, bcount, ccount, dcount, ecount, fcount, gcount, hcount, icount, jcount, kcount, lcount, mcount, ncount, ocount, pcount, qcount, rcount, scount, tcount, ucount, vcount, wcount, xcount, ycount, zcount = 0;
    char *str;

    printf("Enter any string : ");
    gets(str);

    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        if(isalpha(*str))
           {
               toupper(*str);
               switch(*str)
               {
                       case 'A':
                       ++acount;
                       break;

                       case 'B':
                       ++bcount;
                       break;

                       case 'C':
                       ++ccount;
                       break;

                       case 'D':
                       ++dcount;
                       break;

                       case 'E':
                       ++ecount;
                       break;

                       case 'F':
                       ++fcount;
                       break;

                       case 'G':
                       ++gcount;
                       break;

                       case 'H':
                       ++hcount;
                       break;

                       case 'I':
                       ++icount;
                       break;

                       case 'J':
                       ++jcount;
                       break;

                       case 'K':
                       ++kcount;
                       break;

                       case 'L':
                       ++lcount;
                       break;

                       case 'M':
                       ++mcount;
                       break;

                       case 'N':
                       ++ncount;
                       break;

                       case 'O':
                       ++ocount;
                       break;

                       case 'P':
                       ++pcount;
                       break;

                       case 'Q':
                       ++qcount;
                       break;

                       case 'R':
                       ++rcount;
                       break;

                       case 'S':
                       ++scount;
                       break;

                       case 'T':
                       ++tcount;
                       break;

                       case 'U':
                       ++ucount;
                       break;

                       case 'V':
                       ++vcount;
                       break;

                       case 'W':
                       ++wcount;
                       break;

                       case 'X':
                       ++xcount;
                       break;

                       case 'Y':
                       ++ycount;
                       break;

                       case 'Z':
                       ++zcount;
                       break;

               }//Close case
           }//Close if
    }//Close while

    printf("Number of A's: %d", acount);

}
```

Comment: Don't use gets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890696/why-gets-is-deprecated

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory to str. gets requires you to allocate some memory and hope that the user does not type too many letters.

Answer (score 3):

Many errors in your code

1. You don't initialize all the `(x)count` variables to `0`, read about the coma operator.
2. You used `gets()` which is a mean and deprecated function.
3. You passed an uninitialized pointer to `gets()` which is undefined behavior.
4. `toupper(*str)` does not modify `*str`.

Try this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    /* You need an array of int's with size equal to the number of letters
     * int the alphabet
     */
    int count['Z' - 'A' + 1];
    /* You need some space to store the text, `str' will become a poitner
     * when you pass it to `fgets()' pointing to an array of 1000 `chars'
     */
    char str[1000];
    /* Initialize all the counters to 0 */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(count) / sizeof(*count) ; ++i)
        count[i] = 0;
    printf("Enter any string : ");
    /* Read the string, use `fgets()` and prevent a buffer overflow */
    if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1;
    /* Now count the letters */
    for (int i = 0 ; ((str[i] != '\0') && (str[i] != '\n')) ; ++i)
    {
        /* If it's not a letter, go to the next one */
        if (isalpha((int) str[i]) == 0)
            continue;
        /* It's a letter, count it at the correct position */
        count[toupper((int) str[i]) - 'A'] += 1;
    }

    /* Print the count of each letter, skipping those that did not appear */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(count) / sizeof(*count) ; ++i)
    {
        if (count[i] == 0)
            continue;
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of %c's : %d\n", i + 'A', count[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow you're fast. You might want to note that gets is deprecated because it basically guarantees that a user can cause a buffer overflow in your program.

Comment: `((str[i] != '\n') && (str[i] != '\n'))` is redundant and will cause UB if the last line of the file does not end with a linefeed.  Just use `str[i] != '\0'` as you only count letters anyway.  `isalpha(str[i])` should be `isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])` to account for stupid systems where `char` is signed.  For the same reason, you should write `count[toupper((unsigned char)str[i]) - 'A'] += 1;`.  Also be aware that `isalpha` may be true for non-ASCII characters and `toupper` can return values greater than `'Z'` in some locales.

Comment: @chqrlie Of course it is! And `isalpha()` expects `int` not `unsigned char`.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood my remark about `char` signedness.  You need to cast `char` argument to the functions from `<ctype.h>` in order to prevent sign extension of negative characters that will invoke undefined behaviour.  They indeed take an `int` argument, but are only defined for all values of `unsigned char` and the value `EOF`.  See C11, 7.4 paragraph 1.  You should not call `isalpha` with a `char` argument if the type `char` is signed. The simple fix is to cast the `char` value to `unsigned char`, the `unsigned char` value will then be automatically converted to `int`.

Comment: I think this is non-portable `int count['Z' - 'A' + 1];`. In case the execution character set has the alphabet backwards or something like that, this won't work. I'm not sure if there is a portable thing that will do what you're attempting.

Comment: How do I edit this to read in a file?

Comment: @BlakeDoran Use [`fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and pass the handler to `fgets()`.

Comment: Note: In C11, `gets()` is removed.  (passed depreciation)

Answer (score 0):

All remarks in iharob response are correct.  Read my comment on his response for extra problems. Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int counts[256] = { 0 };
    int c;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        counts[c & 255]++;
    }
    printf("Number of A's: %d", counts['a'] + counts['A']);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: here is a solution to handle a file instead of a line of input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long long int counts[256] = { 0 };
    int c;
    FILE *f;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s FILE\n", argv[0]);
        exit(2);
    }
    if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        counts[c & 255]++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Number of A's: %lld", counts['a'] + counts['A']);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can edit this program so it scans a file for the text rather than user input?

Comment: You can simply remove the test for `'\n'` and use command line redirection to read you file via standard input: `myprogram < myfile.txt`.  You might want to use a larger type than `int` for pathological cases where the file has more than 2 billion `'a'`s in it.

Comment: Could you explain more? I am confused

Comment: @Blake Doran: I edited the answer with extra code to handle a file of any length.  The filename is passed as a command line argument.