# Scanf doesn't read string properly in C. What's wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, scanf

I'm writing a code that's supposed to find the spaces in the string and separate the parts before and after them in different string arrays. The first problem would be that the scanf doesn't even read my string properly, but also I haven't worked with strings in C before and am curious if it's correct (especially with the a[] array).

```
char expr[50];
char *a[50];
scanf("%s",expr);
int i=0;
int j=0;

while (strlen(expr)!=0){
    if (expr[i]==' '){
        strncpy(a[j],expr,i);
        strcpy(expr,expr+i+1);
        j++;
        i=0;
    }
    else {
        if (strlen(expr)==1){
            strcpy(a[j],expr);
            strcpy(expr,"");
            j++;
            i=0;
        }
        else i++;
    }

}

i=0;

for (i=0; i<j; i++){
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: scanf by default stops at whitespaces that are not included in the format string. In your case it will read all characters until the first whitespace character into expr, so if your input is a sentence in english, it will grab the first word. If you're looking to grab a whole line, check out the `fgets` function.

Comment: The `%s` conversion specification stops reading at the first white space (blank, tab, newline, etc) — it reads correctly but your expectations are different from its design specification.  Either read the line with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and then use `sscanf()` to parse in stages, or just accept reality and let `scanf()` give you the words one at a time.

Comment: Also `strncpy(a[j],expr,i);` this is bad news, you dont allocate space for the string in `a` this is going to cause `undefined behavior`.

Comment: You also haven't allocated space for the `a[j]` pointers to point at, so `strcpy(a[j], expr);` goes horribly wrong.  It also isn't clear what makes the loop condition fail; I think you have an infinite loop (well, until you crash for accessing memory out of bounds).

Comment: so I corrected these things, and it reads the string correctly, but it only goes through the while once, and the error message is "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it stops reading at the first whitespace *after* a non-whitespace. Leading whitespace is skipped.

Comment: @M.M: yeah, yeah, yeah…RTFM ([`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)) for all the boring details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong.

Firstly, do not use uninitialized `a[j]`.

Add

```
if((a[j]=calloc(strlen(expr)+1,sizeof(char)))==NULL)exit(1);
```

before `strncpy(a[j],expr,i);` and `strcpy(a[j],expr);` to allocate some memory.

Secondary, `strcpy(expr,expr+i+1);` is wrong because `strcpy()` won't accept overlapped regions.

Finally, you should use `scanf("%49s",expr);` instead if `scanf("%s",expr);` to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: so I corrected these things, and it reads the string correctly, but it only goes through the while once, and the error message is "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Comment: What did you replace `strcpy(expr,expr+i+1);` with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `scanf`, use `gets()` for standand input or `fgets()` for reading from a `FILE*`
2. To break a string into elements separated by spaces just use **`strtok`**():

`char expr[50];`

```
gets(expr);

char* a[50];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    a[i] = (char*)malloc(10); // replace 10 with your maximum expected token length
}

i = 0;

for (char* token = strtok(expr, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    strcpy(a[i++], token); 
}

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("%s\n", a[j]);
}


// don't forget to free each a[i] when done.
```

3. For simplicity this sample uses deprecated functions such as **`strcpy`**, consider replacing it with **`strcpy_s`**

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and has been deprecated in C99 and removed in C11, long before 2015. [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714), [Why gets() is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890696/995714)