# Why does freeing the dynamically allocated memory create issue here?

Tags: c, string, free

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* creatString();
void printWordsThatStartWithLETTER(char letter, char *str);

void main()
{
    char *strEx1;
    char letter;
    strEx1=creatString();
    printf("Enter a letter:\n");
    scanf("%c",&letter);
    printWordsThatStartWithLETTER(letter, strEx1);
    free(strEx1);
}

char* creatString()
{
    char *str, *strTemp;
    int size;
    strTemp=(char*)malloc(256);
    printf("enter your string:\n");
    flushall();
    gets(strTemp);
    size = strlen(strTemp);
    str=(char*)malloc(size);
    strcpy(str,strTemp);
    //puts(str);
    free(strTemp);
    return str;
}
void printWordsThatStartWithLETTER(char letter, char *str)
{
    int sizeOfStrinf, i;
    sizeOfStrinf = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<sizeOfStrinf;i++)
    {
        if((str[i]==letter)||(str[i]==letter-32))
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                while(str[i]!=32)
                {
                    printf("%c",str[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
                if(str[i-1]==32)
                {
                    while(str[i]!=32)
                    {
                        printf("%c",str[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

it wont free `strEx1`, I have overflow. How can I free `strEx1` properly?

Comment: **Minimal** code, Input, Observed Output, Expected Output.

Comment: `warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`

Comment: `str=(char*)malloc(size);` --> `str=malloc(size+1);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: It's non-standard, but `strdup()` is widely available:  `str = strdup(strTemp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating memory that is one byte too short. Add one

```
size = strlen(strTemp);    
str=(char*)malloc(size+1);
```

or
instead of strcpy use strncpy

```
size = strlen(strTemp);
str=(char*)malloc(size);
strncpy(str,strTemp,size);
```

The strncpy function copies the initial count characters of strSource to strDest and returns strDest. If count is less than or equal to the length of strSource, a null character is not appended automatically to the copied string. If count is greater than the length of strSource, the destination string is padded with null characters up to length count. The behavior of strncpy is undefined if the source and destination strings overlap

Answer (score 4):

You have the actual issue in your code where you do

```
size = strlen(strTemp);
str=(char*)malloc(size);
```

basically, you're one element short, no space for null-terminator. So later using `strcpy()`

```
 strcpy(str,strTemp);
```

causes out of bound access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should do something like

```
 str = malloc(size + 1);
```

That said,

1. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. Always check the return value of `malloc()` for success before using the return value to avoid null-pointer dereference.
3. [You must not be using `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890696/2173917).