# Multiple line input by gets() function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, char

When i write this code i could not enter two lines as input where each line contains 3 to 5 words by **gets()** function:

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    char nm1[50],nm2[50];
    while(t--)
    {
       gets(nm1);
       gets(nm2);

       puts(nm1);
       puts(nm2);

    }
}
```

But when i add a **gets()** function earlier before **while()** function now i can enter two line of strings like this :

```
int t;
cin>>t;
char nm1[50],nm2[50];
gets(nm1); //using gets() function here//
while(t--)
{
   gets(nm1);
   gets(nm2);

   puts(nm1);
   puts(nm2);
}
```

**So, what is the logic behind this?**

Comment: Why would you even consider using gets()? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890696/why-gets-is-deprecated

Comment: Don't use `gets` in C++.  It is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++14 and beyond.

Comment: The `gets` function is dangerous, as it can overflow buffers.  If you must, use `fgets` instead.  Prefer to use `std::string` in C++ for text.

Comment: Because i have to take input two lines where each line contains five words.

Comment: Your `main` function should return a value to the operating system, such as 0 for success, other numbers for failure.

Comment: You should be using `std::string` to read in words and `std::vector<std::string>` to store the words.  Try this: `std::string word; std::cin >> word;`.

Comment: sorry, i can't understand your explanation.

Comment: @Thomas "Your main function should return a value to the operating system" - I would have thought that someone that posts so much stuff here would know this isn't necessary in C++.

Comment: thank you, i know this. but why this happening for just using one gets() function outside .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `gets`. See [Why gets() is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890696/why-gets-is-deprecated).
2. Don't mix `cin` and functions from `stdio.h`. By default, `cin` is synchronized with `stdin`. However, it is possible to make them stay out of sync by using

   ```
   std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   ```

   See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio for further details.

Real problem.

```
cin >> t;
```

leaves a newline character in the input stream. The next call to `gets` reads that. If you don't want `gets` to read that, you have to add code to read and discard the rest of the line.

Here's what I suggest:

```
int main()
{
   int t;
   cin >> t;

   // Ignore the rest of the line.
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   char nm1[50],nm2[50];
   while(t--)
   {
      cin.get(nm1, 50);
      cin.get(nm2, 50);

      puts(nm1);
      puts(nm2);
   }
}
```

Make sure to dd

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: "Don't mix cin and functions from stdio.h." Please say exactly why not - technically it's perfectly safe; much C++ code would not work if it wasn't.

Comment: Do you recommend reading a whole line, when the requirement is for a word?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, no, I don't. I didn't think I was making that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

in the `cin>>t` you entered a number and then pressed enter `\n`, and the end of line is still waiting in the buffer, if you read another integer `cin>>another_integer`, `cin` will ignore `\n` or `' '` (whitespaces), but gets will not. What you are really typing is something like follows

5`\n`         ---- see the end of line?
my string`\n`
my bigger string`\n`

gets() reads until it find a `\n` or `end of file`

by the way, gets() is deprecated in c++11, you should use getline() or other function instead

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend performing safer I/O using C++ constructs:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int quantity;
  cin >> quantity;
  // Now input the words
  std::vector<std::string> database;
  while (cin >> word)
  {
    database.push_back(word);
  }
  return 0;
}
```