# What alternative can I use instead of gets() and puts()?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, gets

Code snippet for `gets()`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[MAX_SIZE]
    gets(str);
    printf("\n");
```

Code snippet for `puts()`

```
  printf("The most probable key is: %d\n", max2);
  puts(output);
  return 0;
```

I did not paste my whole code since it seems pretty irrelevant for my question. I just want to know a way I could fix this because when I run my code through GCC, it gives me errors and is not allowing me to use `gets()`. How would I fix this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `puts()`

Answer (score 4):

Use `fgets` and `fputs` instead. There is - beside removing all the flaws of `gets`- also a main difference in the usage between `gets` and `fgets`: `fgets` stores a new line character in the buffer (and `gets` does not).

So an equivalent - i.e. eliminating any new line if not desired - could look as follows. Function call `strcspn(buffer,"\n")` gives the longest sequence of characters until a new line is encountered (or strlen(buffer), if the string does not contain a new line). By writing a `0` to the index at this position a new line - if any - is eliminated.

```
char buffer[MAX_SIZE] = "";
if (fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE ,stdin)) {
  buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\n")] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why chose `fputs()` over `puts()`?

Comment: There are several other differences between `gets()` and `fgets()` including the most important one that the total number of input bytes is limited.    The only big difference between `puts()` and `fputs()` is that `fputs()` can write to most any file while `puts()` can only write to `stdout`

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: just for symmetry, since `fgets` takes a FILE stream as explicit parameter, the same could be used for the output side as well.

Comment: @user3629249: clear, there are many differences which led to remove `gets` from the standard. I meant a difference in usage...

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely, positively avoid using `gets()`, [its dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917) and removed from the recent `C` standard. [That's why you see the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890696/2173917)

`C11`, Foreword, Paragraph 6 mentions

> Major changes from the previous edition include:
>
> [....]
>
> - removed the `gets` function (`<stdio.h>`)

Instead, use [`fgets()`.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

---

To add, `puts()` is just fine, I see no reason for replacing that one.

Comment: error: too few arguments to function ‘fgets’  it is giving me this error message when i use fgets()

Comment: @BlytheS. at least read the manual. Nobody said it was a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @BlytheS. Please read the related man page, as linked in the answer.

Comment: is there anyway i can use getchar() instead?

Comment: @BlytheS. Yes, you certainly can, but if your target is to read strings, `fgets()` is the _preferred_ way to go.

Comment: @BlytheS. By asking a new question or search this site on how to use getchar()

Comment: @BlytheS. I strongly suggest you [read the manual first](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar). A basic outline would be, use a loop, read from input one by one until there is buffer element left or you enter a terminating null, and then. end the loop.

Comment: @nos With all due respect sir, how to use `getchar()` would not be good fit for SO. In case there are issues during usage, we'd love to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Never use [`gets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters `gets()` will read, and because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security.

 
Use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead

[`char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

The following [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) shows the usage of `fgets()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   FILE *fp;
   char str[60];

   /* opening file for reading */
   fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      puts(str);
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> alternative can I use instead of gets()

`char str[MAX_SIZE]; gets()` has problems when reading a *line* of `N` characters.  (`N` also counts the `'\n'`).

- When `N > MAX_SIZE`, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Too much input and no place to go.  Often this UB writes into places used by other objects. Bad - very bad.
- C11 eliminated `gets()` and is not a standard function since then.

The usual `fgets()` solution is well suggested by [@Stephan Lechner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456002/2410359).  `fgets()` has some short comings listed below.

1. `str[MAX_SIZE]` now needs to be `str[MAX_SIZE + 1]` as `fgets()` also saves the `'\n'`, unlike `gets()`.  Sometimes adding + 1 is not practical.
2. `fgets()` retains the *potential* `'\n'`.  See [Removing trailing newline character from fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359)
3. When input is excessive, `fgets()` simply does not read it, unlike `gets()`.  This is well behaved (not UB) yet we are still stuck with that problem: how to detect excessive input and what to do about it?

If code can live with these, use `fgets()`.   Otherwise, read on.

---

**`mygets()` alternative**

This function does not need a +1 to the size of the `s` buffer.

Excessively long input returns `NULL`.  All the line is read.  The `s` buffer is filled with the initial characters.

```
char *mygets(char *s, size_t n) {
  char *dest = s;

  // Pathological case of n==0
  char dummy[1];
  if (n == 0) {
    n = sizeof dummy;
    dest = dummy;
  }

  size_t i = 0;
  int ch;
  n--;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (i < n) {
      dest[i++] = (char) ch;
    } else {
      s = NULL; // Not enough room
    }
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {  // end-of-file
      if (i == 0) {
        s = NULL;
      }
    } else { // input error
      i = 0;
      s = NULL;
    }
  }

  dest[i] = '\0';
  return s;
}
```

Subtle bonuses:

- `s` buffer is well defined on rare input error.  With `gets/fgets` buffer contents are then undefined.
- Pathological size of 0 is well defined.  `fgets()` is a bit [iffy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359) on that.
- Buffer size is the idiomatic `size_t` rather than `int` as with `fgets()`.

---

Usage

```
str[MAX_SIZE];

if (mygets(str, sizeof str)) {
  printf("Success <%s>\n", str);
} else {
  if (feof(str)) printf("End of file detected. <%s>\n", str);
  else if (ferror(str)) printf("End of file detected.  <%s>\n", str);
  else printf("Input too long <%s>.", str);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want one `ungetc()` when buffer is too short to avoid losing 1 character.

Comment: @pmg For `mygets()`, the idea is to always consume the entire line and not leave the extra part of the long line in `stdin` - returning an error condition.

Comment: My bad ... I read `s = NULL; /*imagined*/break;`, but you keep reading