# Allocating Memory for a whole line of input of variable length stored as a single string

Tags: c, string, input

I'm learning C and I was reading around what is the best way to take in input line by line.

Basically I want to create strings that hold a whole line of input. The question below doesn't answer how I should handle the memory allocation for the string.

[How can I scan strings with spaces in them using scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726499/how-can-i-scan-strings-with-spaces-in-them-using-scanf)

Should I first detect how much space is needed? How? Should I just realloc every time I need more space?

Please show an example

Input is from a file or from stdin(both will be possible but not at the same time)

Comment: question too general. what do you need to do? where is the input from?

Comment: Well ,if length will change then you would need to use `realloc` .

Comment: I included where the input is from in the question, so remove your downvote

Comment: Depending on platform, you might have a [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function which will allocate memory for you.

Comment: @Helsing If you are on Linux then take a look at `%ms`  .

Answer (score 0):

The following repeatedly allocates buffer storage until the input has been read (malloc/realloc checks omitted):

```
char *myGetLine(FILE *in)
{
    char *buffer= NULL;
    int c, i, j;

    i= 0; j= 0;
    do
    {
        c= fgetc(in);
        if (i==j) {
            j += 1024;
            buffer= realloc(buffer, j);
        }
        if (c==EOF) break;
        buffer[i++]= c;
    } while (1);
    buffer[i]= '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Why use a separate buffer `buf` and do all that copying? Just store into `buffer` if there is space, or re-allocate and then store seems to make more sense.

Comment: Better, but I think you failed to store the incoming character when reallocating.

Comment: Getting there, though. :) It might make sense to return the buffer, to make the function usuble as a reusable building block.

Comment: Also: you don't need the initial malloc. `buff = realloc(NULL, new_size);` works as expected

Comment: @unwind - fixed your comment. Any reason to keep the down vote?

Comment: @BLUEPIX, think I fixed your bug report.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie We're not supposed to say, but I never voted you down for this answer. It will break now if given an empty input, since it will terminate a `NULL` buffer.

Comment: @Unwind, hi; it won't break on empty input; it will always allocate a buffer. It first gets `c`, then checks/allocates the buffer and only then checks for `c==EOF` and breaks if true, so there will always be a buffer to put in the `\0`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie True! #fail.