# inability to input sentences with white space

Tags: c

I'm trying to make the 20 questions game using c. The following is the code excerpt of **one of the functions**.

```
int question_input(void)
{
    char q[100];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter the question or say if you want to guess\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",q);
    i=check_if_guess(q);
    if(i==0)
    {
        printf("Say yes or no\n");
        scanf("%s",q);
    }
    return i;
}
```

I get a general protection fault when I execute and on debugging, I found that the problem is with the

```
scanf("%[^\n]",q)
```

statement.

If the same statement is changed to `"%s"`, then, I get no segmentation fault. Functions like gets (general protection fault) and `fgets`(doesn't ask for input at all) also fail to take inputs.

The thing which is more curious is that when I execute these statements in a seperate file, without the rest of the code, they execute properly.

Even if I try "%99[^\r\n]", it shows the same.

Please help

Comment: You need to show function `check_if_guess` .

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726499/how-can-i-scan-strings-with-spaces-in-them-using-scanf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scan strings with spaces in them using scanf()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726499/how-can-i-scan-strings-with-spaces-in-them-using-scanf)

Comment: have you tried using `fgets` instead?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]",q);` --> `fgets(q, sizeof q, stdin); q[strcspn(q,"\n"]=0;`

Comment: Do not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.   Best to just use `fgets()`.

Comment: @ameyCU The error is with the statement before the check_if_guess function. Hence I don't think, it is required. So please help with this.

Comment: This is bad because you do not limit input to the size of buffer and fail to test the return value of `scanf`. And misuses `scanf` where `fgets` should be used. But it should not be enough to have a general protection fault. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Derlin and Gaurav Pathak I tried "%99[^\r\n]" just now. It still didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisTurner and chux, I did try using fgets also. It didn't even take an input from me. Just skipped it.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? We might be able to spot something. gets or fgets not taking input is not normal.

Comment: or show us how you used `fgets`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I just replaced the scanf statement with fgets(q,100,stdin)

Comment: @SiddharthKailasam that is right, so it must be something to do with the rest of your code. maybe you're not processing the `\n` from the previous line first?

Comment: @MohammedBakrSikal Pls share ur mail id so that I could mail u the code

Comment: @SiddharthKailasam replace the spaces in my name with dots, and the rest is gmail generic stuff

Comment: @ChrisTurner Processing the \n? What does that mean?

Comment: @SiddharthKailasam `fgets` stops as soon as it gets a `\n` or it runs out of buffer space. because we can't see the rest of your code, we don't know what else it is doing - it might be reading in part of a line and then calling this function.

Comment: @MohammedBakrSikal it said mail address not found.

Comment: @ChrisTurne rpls send me ur mail id also, so that I can send it to u too

Comment: try `scanf(" %99[^\n]", q);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer to my question by myself. One of my previous functions in my code had

> scanf("%d",&n)

It is a known fact that after we enter our input we press the enter key. This is taken as a '\n' by the compiler and is stored in the buffer. My next scanf statement( the one which I got error in)(scanf("%[^\n]",q) straight away took the '\n' from the buffer. Hence it could not take any input, since \n terminates input. The compiler I use is turbo C++. In **some** cases of empty strings, it reports an error. Hence I got the error message. To solve this problem, I had to use

> getchar()

statement before the scanf("%[^\n]",q) statement, so that the '\n' is removed from the buffer and taken as an input for the getchar statement.