# how to input two space separated word in c which one word can be omitted sometimes

Tags: c, string, input, while-loop, scanf

What I want to do is to input two words in C but one word can be omitted sometimes.
To be more precise **there is exactly one word necessarily and the other number of words may vary. which can be zero ,one , two or three**
 As an example sometimes the input can be

> **Hello world**

while sometimes it can be just

> **Hello**

the reason why i want this to be done is I'm taking inputs in a while loop
(I have to take input continuously and process according to them)
I have used

> **`"%s %[^\n]%*c"`**

but it waits until I enter another word. (Because its expecting a another word after space)

I tried googling and all the aspects of scanf but didn't find any solution.
Any help appreciated ! Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scan strings with spaces in them using scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726499/how-can-i-scan-strings-with-spaces-in-them-using-scanf)

Comment: What does it mean "sometimes"

Comment: scanf gets a string which may or may not contain any number of spaces, to split it into words you need to parse the string once it has arrived - this is why scanf information on the web isn't helping you.

Comment: Why not simply [read the whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) as a single string?

Comment: Why don't you just read your strings and don't omit them in the loop?

Comment: Do you know that you can stop the input by pressing ctr+d on linux? Or does your program do the right thing when you take the input from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` does not seem to be the right tool for your purpose, you should instead read one line at a time with `fgets()` and process it according to the words that are present.

If you insist on using `scanf()`, `"%s %[^\n]%*c"` does not work because the space matches newlines. Assuming array sizes of 20 bytes, you could use `"%19[^ \t\n]%*[ \t]%19[^ \t\n]"` and check the return value to see how many words have been read on a single line (`0`, `1`, `2` or `EOF`), but if you expect a variable number of words, `fgets()` is a much preferred solution.

Here is an example for up to 3 words per line:

```
int scan_input(void) {
    char word1[20], word2[20], word3[20];
    int n, c;

    for (;;) {
        switch (n = scanf("%19[^ \t\n]%*[ \t]%19[^ \t\n]%*[ \t]%19[^ \t\n]",
                          word1, word2, word3)) {
          case EOF:
            return EOF;
          case 0:
            /* no word on the line, skip the empty line */
            break;
          case 1:
            /* one word on the line */
            printf("1 word: %s\n", word1);
            break;
          case 2:
            /* two word on the line */
            printf("2 words: %s %s\n", word1, word2);
            break;
          case 3:
            /* three word on the line */
            printf("3 words: %s %s\n", word1, word2, word3);
            break;
        }
        /* ignore the rest of the line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
}
```

Here is an example using `fgets()`:

```
int scan_input(void) {
    char buf[256];
    int n, pos, len;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        /* scan the line, skipping whitespace */
        for (n = 1, pos = 0; buf[pos += strspn(buf, " \t\n")] != '\0'; n++) {
            /* compute the word length */
            len = strcspn(buf + pos, " \t\n");
            /* found word at offset `pos` of length `len` bytes */
            printf("word %d: %.*s\n", n, len, buf + pos);
            pos += len;
        }
    }
    return EOF;
}
```

Comment: I tend to think `scanf()` is never the right tool ;) But if someone insists using it, what's **always forbidden** is a conversion to a string without a field width.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: of course... I initially had a remark to this end, but will provide an actual example for illustration

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where **not** using `scanf()` is astonishingly simple:

```
char line[1024];

while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) 
{
    char *word = strtok(line, " \t\n");
    while (word)
    {
        // do something with word
        word = strtok(0, " \t\n"); // <- next word
    }
}
```

As for `scanf()` and how/why not to use it, I suggest reading my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

---

Side note: `strtok()` isn't thread-safe. If this is a concern, there are alternatives like the POSIX `strtok_r()` or the C11 `strtok_s()`. Beware Microsoft also has a `strtok_s()` which is *different* from the standard C version.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem if you want **omit** one word sometimes. But i would recommend you not using `scanf()`use `fgets()`instead and process your string after you have read it.

**Syntax**

```
char chr[MAX];
while(i<10){
     fgets(chr,MAX, stdin);
}
```

If you want to omit your second word, just check for a whitespace in your `string` and terminate it on that place/index the String with `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that `scanf()` is probably not the right tool here.

Another way could be to use `fgets()` and `strchr()` and a pointer as in

```
char str[100], *ptr;

while( (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin))!=NULL ){
    if( (ptr=strchr(str, '\n'))!=NULL )
    {
        *ptr=0;
    }   
    if( (ptr=strchr(str, ' '))!=NULL )
    {
        *ptr=0;
        ptr++;
        if( strchr(ptr, ' ')==NULL )
        {
            printf("\nTwo words: %s, %s", str, ptr);    
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nMore than two words!");
        }
    }   
    else//only one word
    {
        printf("\nOne word: %s", str);
    }
}
```

`fgets()` is used to read in the input into a character array `str`. `fgets()` returns `NULL` on error.

Since `fgets()` also reads in any trailing `\n`, we check the string for `\n` if it's there, it's replaced with a `\0` to denote end of string in the

```
if( (ptr=strchr(str, '\n'))!=NULL )
{
    *ptr=0;
}
```

part.

`strchr()` returns `NULL` if the searched character is not present in the string.

`strchr()` is again used to check for a space in `str`. If none is found, only one word was read and otherwise multiple words were input.

If more than one word is there, the space is replaced with a `\0` using the pointer returned by `strchr()` so that doing a

```
printf("%s", str);
```

will now print only the first word and the pointer is incremented so that it now points to the beginning of the second word. This is done in

```
if( (ptr=strchr(str, ' '))!=NULL )
{
    *ptr=0;
    ptr++;
```

Now, `strchr()` is once again used to check for another case in which case more than two words were input. Otherwise only two words were input and the second word is output using

```
printf("%s", ptr);
```

You could use a similar approach to read more words.